# How to get the tokenids of certain ERC721 tokens for a adress? using Web3py

Tags: python, ethereum, smartcontracts, nft, web3py

A known way:

1. call *balanceOf* to get the number of tokens owned by the address call
2. Call *tokenOfOwnerByIndex* in a loop to get each owned token ID.

But what I'm very confused about is what to do when the ERC721 contract has not included  *tokenOfOwnerByIndex* function

Answer (score 0):

`tokenOfOwnerByIndex` is what most token will provide for you to enumerate in, but you could use `Transfer` event on that contract to do that also

Comment: Use code formatting for code names in order to improve readibility